# How to fail on parse many with parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Apoligies if this is a trivial thing, but I really can't find it out on my own.

**PRELIMINARIES**

I have a file with many entries like `FOO <value>`, For Example:

```
# example.txt
FOO 5
FOO 9
```

Such a file read as a string would be `FOO 5\nFOO 9\n`. I tried to parse these with

```
parseFoo :: ParsecT String u Identity (String, Int)
parseFoo = do
    k <- string "FOO"
    _ <- space
    v <- many1 digit
    return (k, read v)

parseFoos :: ParsecT String u Identity [(String, Int)]
parseFoos = parseFoo `endBy` newline

testFOO :: Either ParseError [(String, Int)]
testFOO = parse parseFoos "" "FOO 5\nFOO 6\n"
```

This gives me `Right [("FOO",5),("FOO",6)]` as expected.

**MY QUESTION**

How to fail parsing on invalid inputs?

For example: `parse parseFoos "" "BLAH"` returns `Right []`, but I want the parser to fail.

For example: `parse parseFoos "" "FOO 5\nBAR 7\n"` returns `Right [("FOO", 5)]`, but I want the parser to fail.

Comment: ``parseFoo `endBy` newLine <* eof``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should match EOF at the end of the parser. Use the provided `eof` to do it. Without `eof` the parser will not match the end of file, and will happily parse only part of the input.

In the `do` block:

```
do
    res <- {- Your parser code here -}
    eof
    return res
```

Or just use the <* operator: `parser <* eof` will do.